# TinyButStrong update for PHP 8.1?

Tags: tinybutstrong

I've recently updated our server to PHP 8.1 and the latest version of TinyButStrong. The latter now throws a fatal error:

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot acquire reference to $GLOBALS in U:\ivojoadmin\tinybutstrong3\tbs_class.php on line 713

The line in question reads:

$this->VarRef =& $GLOBALS;

I've read up a bit on 8.1 and this type of assignment is no longer allowed but is there any way of getting TinyButStrong working again without downgrading PHP?

Answer (score 1):

The next TBS and OpenTBS versions will be compatible with PHP 8.1.
Beta versions are already available on GitHub.

https://github.com/Skrol29/tinybutstrong

https://github.com/Skrol29/opentbs

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem; I try the beta version but it's the same thing

```
TinyButStrong Error in field [var.menu...]: parameter script with value '[val]' cannot be called because the current TBS settings do not allow to call scripts. This message can be cancelled using parameter 'noerr'.
```

Without the complete code i know it's not easy but he is on many files.

Thank's a lot

Comment: But I asked a question about it, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75572598/bug-after-php-update,  which is the way to go!   (Please delete this anser because it is not an answer!)