# Bug after php update

Tags: php, tinybutstrong

I have a bug on my application after upgrading my php version. The 8.0 php version is ok but if I try to update on 8.1 or 8.2 my appication block with an error I don't understand.

```
TinyButStrong Error in field [var.menu...]: parameter script with value '[val]' cannot be called because the current TBS settings do not allow to call scripts. This message can be cancelled using parameter 'noerr'.
```

My application block on the identification page. I use the last tinybutstrong version. I tried the beta version but no changed.

If you have a solution ?

Thank's.

Comment: Does this help: [This error message can happen when you're forgotten a closing character (\]).](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/forum.php?thr=3214#:~:text=This%20error%20message%20can%20happen%20when%20you%27re%20forgotten%20a%20closing%20character%20(%5D).)  ?   When it does not help please add source code with example of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since TBS version 3.14.0 , parameter script is not allowed by default. This is a security option.

You can enable parameter script doing :

```
$TBS->SetOption('scripts_allowed', true);
```